Randomization and Causal Dags
Suppose we have Treatment T and Outcome O, and variables A and B, with the following causal dag:
But if we were doing an RCT with these treatment and outcome variables, is it accurate to think of the causal dag then turning into:

Where the incoming arrows to T are gone?

Do downvoters have any specific reason for doing so? Has this question been asked?

Yes, that is correct. A and B no longer affect T, because T is determined by randomisation that is independent of A and B.   Some people might put another node on the graph for 'randomisation', either to make the point or to allow the graph to represent imperfect compliance/adherence

Thanks for the response. When you say " Some people might put another node on the graph for 'randomisation',", is this node have an outgoing arrow going towards the treatment? or its just like a root  nodes with no children?

Randomisation ->Treatmeant
